# QTP download QTPWEB_00086 patch file

Tags: qtp

Recently i  downloaded and started QTP 11 on Windows 7. I need to insatll a "QTPWEB_00086" patch.Can anyone tell where i can find the patch file for download  except hp website.

Answer (score 1):

To get patch QTPWeb_00086 you need to request it from HP support only.

Comment: it keep asking me a contract identifier number (SAID)  which i don't have. some other location ?

Comment: No support contract -- no SAID. No SAID -- no support services. No support services -- no patches. It is that easy. You are asking for material that is available only as part of a paid support service.